# how to compare +0.00 to -0.00 in xsl such that result says those are equal

Tags: xslt

I have this kind of xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<data>
    <point>
        <x>0.000</x>
        <y>100.0</y>
    </point>
    <point>
        <x>-0.000</x>
        <y>100.0</y>
    </point>
</data>
```

I am applying this kind of xsl to this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="point1_x" select="data/point[1]/x/text()"/>
        <xsl:variable name="point2_x" select="data/point[2]/x/text()"/>
        <xsl:if test="$point1_x != $point2_x">x values are different</xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="$point1_x = $point2_x">x values are same</xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I get result that "x values are different".

What I want is "x values are same".

Can anyone please suggest how to do that? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare numbers:

```
   <xsl:variable name="point1_x" select="number(data/point[1]/x)"/>
   <xsl:variable name="point2_x" select="number(data/point[2]/x)"/>
```